# Mouseover color change in HSL mode

Tags: jquery, mouseover, background-color

I found this code on another thread to change the background color with mouseover:

```
var $win = $(window),
w = 0,h = 0,
rgb = [],
getWidth = function() {
    w = $win.width();
    h = $win.height();
};

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

rgb = [
    Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
    Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
    150
];

$(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
```

Is it possible to convert this to HSL mode in a very simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You'll only have to define the lightness (the L in HSL) manually, which is comparable to how blue is handled in your example.

```
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    hsl = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

    hsl = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 360),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 100) + "%",
        50 + "%"
    ];

    $(document.body).css('background','hsl('+hsl.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
```